# Unterschied zwischen »finden« und »auffinden«

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

> Gestern wurde ein Mann tot in der Badewanne aufgefunden.

Warum verwendet man das Verb *auffinden* in diesem Kontext?

Wird es sich die Bedeutung des Satzes dadurch ändern, wenn man es so schreibt:

> Gestern wurde ein Mann tot in der Badewanne gefunden.

Ist *auffinden* etwas formeller als *finden?*

Sind es noch Vorschläge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ergänzung zur Antwort von Benjoyo:

"auffinden" ist ein Synonym von "entdecken", das [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=auffinden) führt das Verb in der Synonymengruppe von

> (zufällig) begegnen,  antreffen,  auffinden,  entdecken,  finden, 
>   identifizieren,  stoßen auf,  vorfinden,

wobei jene Begriffe im Vordergrund stehen, die die unerwartete Begegnung implizieren.

"Finden" steht hingegen mit "suchen" in Verbindung. Wenn man nach einer lebenden Person sucht, findet man sie, wenn sie lebt, im anderen Fall findet man sie tot auf. Sucht man nach einer Leiche, findet man die Leiche, wenn man sie schließlich entdeckt. Der Antwort von Benjoyo entspricht es wiederum, dass man eine lebende Person nicht "auffindet", wenn man sie irgendwo zufällig bzw. unerwartet antrifft.

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz funktioniert auf jeden Fall auch mit *finden*. Allerdings benutzt man im Zusammenhang mit der Entdeckung einer Leiche fast immer "jmd. tot auffinden". *Auffinden* wird meistens bei leblosen oder hilflosen Lebewesen benutzt. Genauso würde auch *vorfinden* gehen. Beide haben so etwa die Bedeutung "auf etw. stoßen", auch wenn es natürlich feine Unterschiede gibt.

Comment: Könnte der Unterschied auch im Zusammenhang mit *suchen* sein?

Comment: Du meinst man benutzt _finden_ eher, wenn man vorher explizit etwas gesucht hat?

Comment: ja, so ist mein Eindruck - oder anders herum, man benutzt *auffinden* nicht, wenn man nicht vorher gesucht hat.

Comment: Ja, so herum würde ich das auch sagen. Andersrum wird es zumindest benutzt. Man sagt ja "Ich habe ihn so gefunden.", auch wenn man bestimmt nach keiner Leiche gesucht hat.

Comment: Das "auffinden" hat für mich den Charakter von Amtsdeutsch/Behördendeutsch. Da drückt man sich immer etwas "feiner" aus.

Answer (score 0):

Was man "findet" ist verborgen.

Was main "auffindet" ist in klarer Sicht, aber aus dem Weg.

"Ein Mann tot in der Badewanne" ist der Letztere.